# Specifying a default argument in pom.xml and overriding it in the command line

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

The only function of my main class is to read from an xml config file, which I'm currently specifying in the command line. Is it possible to make it so a default config file is specified in pom.xml, so if the program is run from the command line without passing in an argument, that config file is read, but if an argument is passed in with -Dexec.args the default is overridden?

Comment: how are you executing that java? with `mvn exec:java` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm very new to maven so I thought that would be the simplest way.

Comment: yes you can do that probably, I will try to create an answer, stay tuned.

Comment: Short answer is yes-ish.  You could probably use Maven file filter to do something like this.  But the target would be an external file not your actual class.  I don't really see what you are driving at here.  There isn't any obvious benefit to having maven do this vs just hard coding it yourself.

Comment: @Terry Honestly I don't really see it either, but I was told to do so and I can't really dispute it :p. I'm guessing it's more of a big picture thing for later in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at first look at exec plugin documentation [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

in your maven in properties specify your default property which you want look at `my.custom.property`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.debug>true</maven.compiler.debug>
        <!-- frameworks -->

        <!-- properties -->
        <my.custom.property>MAVEN</my.custom.property>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>test.Test</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${my.custom.property}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is java class

```
package test;

import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(args)
                .forEach(arg -> System.out.println("ARGUMENT " + arg));
    }
}
```

and if you execute `mvn compile exec:java` you should see somewhere outpu ARGUMENT MAVEN. If you provide your own argument eg. `mvn compile exec:java -Dmy.custom.property=TEST` you should see ARGUMENT TEST somewhere in console.